# android not clearing sharedpreference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to clear all the sharedpref i put on my first activity and delete it on 2nd activity. But the clear function is not working.. here is my code

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "ResumePrefs";

    SharedPreferences settings;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        try{
            Toast. makeText(this,settings.getString("answer_id",""),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
                 settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 1);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("answer_id", "This is a test");
                editor.commit();
                     Intent intent = new Intent(this,destroyPref.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and my2nd activty:

```
public class destroyPref extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "ResumePrefs";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.destroy);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,1);
        settings.edit().clear();
        settings.edit().commit();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,1);
        settings.edit().clear();
        settings.edit().commit();
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Once i pressed the back button i will go back to the main activity and expect that the preference value is cleared, unless i pressed again the button. I tried bot backpress and resume but still the sharedpref value is still there.. Am i missing something? Thanks.

Comment: you sure onBackPressed is being called?

Comment: have you tried it using `settings.edit().apply()` instead of commit(); ?

Comment: Yes im sure.. I put a toast in there just now and it showed upon pressing the back button.

Comment: Try `settings.edit().clear().commit();`

You're possibly creating a new editor and committing with no changes.

Comment: There is no word apply() showing in intelij.

Comment: @thenewbie try with the solution I have posted.

Comment: @DeeV I think it work, can you post it as an answer?. but you know how to destroy a sharedpref? so that value returns as null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why copy someone elses answer (at first incorrectly) which is then being accepted?

Comment: @Lieuwe check the time I posted 9 mins ago and you posted 8 mins ago. Sounds fair, right?

Comment: And my answer in the comments was 13 minutes ago.  This was just a very easy answer to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

The issue you're facing here is that with the code:

```
   SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,1);
   settings.edit().clear();
   settings.edit().commit();
```

You are creating two editors.  One is set to clear, but you never commit it so it doesn't clear. The other commits, but you never set it to do anything.

```
   SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,1);
   settings.edit().clear().commit();
```

This will create one editor, set it to clear, then commit the changes.  I am *pretty* sure that the values will be nulled out when you return.  I don't honestly know though so please post the results and I'll edit this answer.

Comment: ahm i think it just clear the value of the pref value but not destroy it. cause the toast is returning a blank "" instead an exception because its null. I thin the remove() would destroy. Thanks by the way.

Comment: That could be because you're setting a default value of "" which is what it will return when the key can't be found.

Answer (score 4):

settings.edit() creates a new editor. The commit() is done on a different editor then your clear(). You need to:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't refresh `settings` when you resume your first activity.  Therefore it hasn't read in the new values.